# Special characters in speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am wondering if there is a way to recognize special characters (`@`, `-`, `.`, `_`) with Android SpeechRecognizer?

Comment: I don't think there are some special keywords, but you can provide your own. It depends of your implementation, you didn't provide any so it is hard to say if it is useful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's speech recognizer (i.e. the interfaces and classes in [android.speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html)) return strings. Some of these strings (or their substrings) might be equivalent to e.g. `@` but you have no way of demanding that (e.g. by settings extras). Your best option is to observe how your favorite speech recognizer works and, assuming that it (always) maps the sound /at sign/ to the phrase "at sign", remap it to `@` in your application.

Comment: My requirement is to speak what's your name, speech recognizer does not consider apostrophes. How can we resolve it?